Teams Owner connection to SharePoint severed, how to restore?
Someone recommended I try asking my question here. I personally don't have Powershell or SP Admin Centre access but my company's IT, despite using MS 365 deeply, doesn't appear to have very advanced MS 365 support for Teams or SP.
Users were having an issue where they could not edit SharePoint pages. We couldn't resolve it so our Admin contacted Microsoft support.
Support told me to delete the Owner and Member groups displaying in the permissions list. I was skeptical and asked if they were sure because I think it's related to the Teams permissions (I asked many times, some people may have gotten annoyed), but they still had me delete both the Member and Owner domain groups, leaving behind only the SharePoint equivalent groups.
This immediately made all Members lose access to files, and all Owners lost access. I should've been more persistent.
I was able to find the Members group and add them into the SharePoint Member group, but not back into the permissions list.
The Owners domain group is gone. And I had to manually add all the Owners into the SharePoint group for owners. Now permissions between Teams and SharePoint doesn't work.
It's too late for a point in time restoration, which they should've suggested immediately and didn't consider until I mentioned it, so what other solutions are there?
I am not a tech specialist and so I did not want to be arrogant to continue arguing against deleting those groups with someone from MS, but now I wish I had been because this is a complete mess.
I'm thankful for any clues to help resolve this.
The only thing I've found is about creating new groups in permsetup and then running a PowerShell script, but if it doesn't work completely with no errors, my company's admin will not troubleshoot it/try to get it to work. So I just need some solid solution that they can use "off the shelf".

It's too late... what about engaging someone who is technically qualified?

@GregAskew Microsoft support should be technically qualified. Unfortunately, this is not the first time I see them making a mess :/

It sounds like my hands are tied. MS support said nothing can be done (I found the powershell solution which I don't even know if they have tested before asking our admin to do it), and my company's admin relied on MS support and won't go further than a "off the shelf" solution.
Sounds like it'll be a manual update of permissions then. Thanks all.

You should ask Microsoft support to escalate this to someone who actually know what s/he is doing.
You had a problem and they made it worse; now it's their responsibility to fix it.

If only it was working that way. Thanks Massimo, looks like I'll be manually updating permissions from now on.
